# Datastore: Create parent and child entity in an entity group transaction?

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

After reading about Google Datastore concepts/theory I started using the [Go datastore package](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/datastore#example-Transaction)

Scenario:
Kinds `User` and `LinkedAccount` require that every user has one or more linked accounts (yay 3rd party login). For strong consistency, LinkedAccounts will be children of the associated User. New User creation then involves creating both a User and a LinkedAccount, never just one.

User creation seems like the perfect use case for transactions. If, say LinkedAccount creation fails, the transaction rolls back an fails. This doesn't currently seem possible. The goal is to create a parent and then a child within a transaction.

According to docs

> All Datastore operations in a transaction must operate on entities in
>   the same entity group if the transaction is a single group transaction

We want a new `User` and `LinkedAccount` to be in the same group, so to me it sounds like Datastore should support this scenario. My fear is that the intended meaning is that operations on *existing* entities in the same group can be performed in a single transaction.

```
tx, err := datastore.NewTransaction(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
incompleteUserKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "User", nil)
pendingKey, err := tx.Put(incompleteUserKey, user)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
incompleteLinkedAccountKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "GithubAccount", incompleteUserKey)
// also tried PendingKey as parent, but its a separate struct type
_, err = tx.Put(incompleteLinkedAccountKey, linkedAccount)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
// attempt to commit
if _, err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
    return err
}
return nil
```

From the [library source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang) its clear why this doesn't work. `PendingKey`'s aren't keys and incomplete keys can't be used as parents.

Is this a necessary limitation of Datastore or of the library? For those experienced with this type of requirement, did you just sacrifice the strong consistency and make both kinds global?

For Google-ability:

- datastore: invalid key
- datastore: cannot use pendingKey as type *"google.golang.org/cloud/datastore".Key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to note is that transactions in the Cloud Datastore API [can operate on up to 25 entity groups](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview#Datastore_Transactions_and_entity_groups), but this doesn't answer the question of how to create two entities in the same entity group as part of a single transaction.

There are a few ways to approach this (note that this applies to any use of the Cloud Datastore API, not just the `gcloud-golang` library):

1. Use a (string) name for the parent key instead of having Datastore automatically assign a numeric ID:

   ```
   parentKey := datastore.NewKey(ctx, "Parent", "parent-name", 0, nil)
   childKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "Child", parentKey)
   ```
2. Make an explicit call to `AllocateIds` to have the Datastore pick a numeric ID for the parent key:

   ```
   incompleteKeys := [1]*datastore.Key{datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "Parent", nil)}
   completeKeys, err := datastore.AllocateIDs(ctx, incompleteKeys)
   if err != nil {
     // ...
   }
   parentKey := completeKeys[0]
   childKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "Child", parentKey)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose my question really boils down to 'can pending/incomplete keys be used as a sort of "promise" in a transaction' and it seems the answer is no. I prefer your suggestion using AllocateIds bc I would like Datastore to pick the numeric ID, but the downside is AllocateIds isn't available in transactions. I'll explore these approaches and return

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice way to summarize it, and you're correct that it's not currently supported. As for AllocateIds: it is non-transactional in the sense that the allocation isn't be rolled back if the transaction fails, but that doesn't stop you from calling it while the transaction is active. If the transaction fails, you just end up allocating an ID that doesn't get used -- no big deal.

Comment: This weekend I took the AllocateIDs approach to do transactions requiring the key be complete and decided its pretty unlikely I'd ever need to reclaim allocated but unused ids because the space is so large.